# i m unable to calculate the total after loop

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

i m unable to calculate the total poperty price and commision help plzzz 
my variables are prop and commission 
program run perfect but the transaction summarry lead to last loop calculation i need to total all of loop calculation i made

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loopingS {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    String code, decision;
    int price =0;
    double residential, commercial, multidwelling;
    boolean yesno = true;
    boolean repeat = true;
    boolean cde = true;
    double total=0;
    boolean yn = true;
    double prop=0;
    double commission=0;
  System .out.println("Real-estate Commission Calculator");
  System.out.println("----------------------------------");
  while (yn){

     while(repeat){
          System.out.print("Enter property's selling price: ");
          price = kbd.nextInt();
         if (price <= 0) {
                System.out.println("**error**selling price must be greater than zero ");
                repeat = true;
            }
            else{
                prop=0 + price;
                while(cde){
                    System.out.println("residential         R\nmulti-dwelling     M\nCommercial           C");
                    System.out.println("Enter property code: ");
                    code = kbd.next();  
                    switch(code){
                        case "r":
                        residential = price * 0.07;
                        cde = false;
                        total = +residential;
                        break;

                        case "m":
                        multidwelling = price * 0.06;
                        cde = false;
                        total = + multidwelling;
                        break;

                        case "c":
                        commercial = price * 0.035;
                        cde = false;
                        total = +commercial;
                        break;

                        default:
                        System.out.println("**error**- Property code must be R,M,C");
                        cde = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    commission=0 + total;
                }
         }
         cde = true;
         break;
     }
   System.out.println("Do u want to calculate another commission(y or n): ");
   decision = kbd.next();
     switch(decision){
         case"y":
         yn = true;
         break;

         case "n":
         System.out.println("*********Transacction Summary************");
         System.out.println("Total Property Sale: " +prop);
         System.out.println("Total Commissions: " + commission);
         yn = false;
         break;

         default :
         System.out.println("**Error**Enter valid response");
         yesno = true;
         while(yesno){
             System.out.println("do you want to calculate another commsion(y or n):");
             decision = kbd.nextLine();
             switch(decision){
                 case "y":
                 yn=yesno= true;
                 break;

                 case "n":
                 yn=yesno= false;
                 break;
                }
         } 
    }
  }

  }

  }
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, so I'm guessing a bit, but what happens if you change `commission=0 + total;` to `commission += total;` ?

Comment: Incidentally, you should **never** store an amount of money in a `double` variable, as errors will be introduced when you start doing arithmetic.  You should use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: You often omit letters in English. Also in your code comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        String code, decision;
        int price = 0;
        double residential, commercial, multidwelling;
        boolean yesno = true;
        boolean repeat = true;
        boolean cde = true;
        double total = 0;
        boolean yn = true;
        double prop = 0;
        double commission = 0;
        System.out.println("Real-estate Commission Calculator");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        while (yn)
        {

            while (repeat)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter property's selling price: ");
                price = kbd.nextInt();
                if (price <= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("**error**selling price must be greater than zero ");
                    repeat = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    prop = prop + price;
                    while (cde)
                    {
                        System.out.println("residential         R\nmulti-dwelling     M\nCommercial           C");
                        System.out.println("Enter property code: ");
                        code = kbd.next();
                        switch (code)
                        {
                        case "r":
                            residential = price * 0.07;
                            cde = false;
                            total = +residential;
                            break;

                        case "m":
                            multidwelling = price * 0.06;
                            cde = false;
                            total = +multidwelling;
                            break;

                        case "c":
                            commercial = price * 0.035;
                            cde = false;
                            total = +commercial;
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("**error**- Property code must be R,M,C");
                            cde = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        commission = commission + total;
                    }
                }
                cde = true;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Do u want to calculate another commission(y or n): ");
            decision = kbd.next();
            switch (decision)
            {
            case "y":
                yn = true;
                break;

            case "n":
                System.out.println("*********Transacction Summary************");
                System.out.println("Total Property Sale: " + prop);
                System.out.println("Total Commissions: " + commission);
                yn = false;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("**Error**Enter valid response");
                yesno = true;
                while (yesno)
                {
                    System.out.println("do you want to calculate another commsion(y or n):");
                    decision = kbd.nextLine();
                    switch (decision)
                    {
                    case "y":
                        yn = yesno = true;
                        break;

                    case "n":
                        yn = yesno = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        kbd.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem.